# How to stop R from creating empty Rplots.pdf file when using ggsave and Rscript

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an R script that saves some plots using ggsave. When I run the script from the command line, it not only saves my plots but also an empty Rplots.pdf file. How can I prevent R from creating this unnecessary file?

Here is an example script that reproduces the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

# Code that creates unnecessary Rplots.pdf file
library(ggplot2)
my.data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
my.plot <- qplot(x, y, data = my.data)
ggsave('example.png', my.plot)
```

All the following ways of running the script create the unnecessary file:

```
Rscript script.R
Rscript --vanilla script.R
chmod a+x script.R
./script.R
```

Also, when I source the code from within an interactive session, an unnecessary blank R Graphics Device window opens.

Furthermore, I do not have these problems if I use the the following more verbose code in place of ggsave:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

# Code that does NOT create unnecessary Rplots.pdf file
library(ggplot2)
my.data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
my.plot <- qplot(x, y, data = my.data)
png(file = 'example.png')
print(my.plot)
dev.off()
```

Here is my session info (which is the same whether running Rscript or interactively):

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] methods   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-2   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.3       grid_3.0.1        
 [5] gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.1       MASS_7.3-26        munsell_0.4       
 [9] plyr_1.8           proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.2    
[13] scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2
```

**Update 5 years later (2018-08-02)**: This problem comes and goes. ggplot2 2.2.1 does not produce the empty file, ggplot2 3.0.0 does, and the ggplot2 team is currently working to fix this. For development history, see ggplot2 Issues [#1326](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1326), [#2363](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2363), [#2758](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2758), and [#2787](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2787).

Comment: If I specify a height and width in `ggsave` it appears to fix your problem, but I confess that I do not immediately know why...if I had to guess it's because the defaults are the dimensions of the "current plotting window" which would need to exist before it could measure them.

Comment: I ran `ggsave` and it didn't create `RPlots.pdf`, only `example.pdf`. `ggsave` is relatively straightforward in `debug` mode, you could try that and see what function `device` is calling.

Comment: I do see this behavior, and specifying the height and width arguments seems to resolve it both in an interactive session and using RScript.

Comment: I can confirm this. @joran, maybe that's worth a bug report?

Comment: @Roland I'd want to solicit some opinions on whether anyone finds this behavior desirable first. _I_ don't like it, but it's not obvious to me that no one would prefer it.

Comment: I seem to remember prior reports of something like this issue. You might want to search SO , the forums that are maintained for ggplot2/plyr/reshape2 questions, and the bug logs at github.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you look at the defaults for the width and height arguments in `ggsave`, you'll see that they are `par("din")[1]` and `par("din")[2]`. If you run this in the console, you'll see that it opens a graphics window, if one isn't already open.

This sort of makes sense, since in order to get the device width/height in inches, you need an actual device. I suppose one could argue that `par("din")` should return an error if no device is open, in which case Hadley surely would have written `ggsave` differently.

Indeed, from `?par`:

> If the current device is the null device, par will open a new device
>   before querying/setting parameters.

Hence, specifying a width/height will prevent the spurious device from opening.

Comment: Thanks, @joran! Specifying the height and width to avoid the `par('din')` calls does fix the issue.

Comment: This did not work for me (R 3.0.2; ggplot 0.9.3.1); I still get the `Rplots.pdf` in addition to the png (or pdf) file I specified with `filename`. Maybe it has something to do with the `device` parameter?

Comment: @knowah Not sure; this solution still works for me on R 3.1.0 and ggplot2 1.0.0 (I just tested it again using the exact code from the question.)

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me (R 3.1.0, ggplot2 1.0.0). I added dimensions as parameters to all `ggsave()` calls (PDF and SVG) in an R module, but file `Rplots.pdf` is still being generated. I think it might have worked before, but I have recently upgraded my server...

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use the package [R.devices](https://cran.r-project.org/package=R.devices) to suppress the graphics device opened by `ggsave`:

```
library(R.devices)
suppressGraphics(ggsave('example.png', my.plot))
```

See the [tweet](https://twitter.com/henrikbengtsson/status/1024565925658480651) from the package author for another example.